# How to copy column from one table into another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to copy column state_name from table state into table district.
here is my query.

This code is working on mysql but not in SQL Server

```
UPDATE district,state
SET    district.state_name = state.state_name
WHERE  district.state_id = state.id
```

[image]

This is the `state` table

[image]

This is the `district` table

Comment: If you're using SQL Server (per your title) why tag MySQL as well? That image, however, looks like PHPMyAdmin, which *does not* work with SQL Server. What RDBMS are you *really* using. Update your tags accordingly

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, `UPDATE district,state` isn't valid syntax. An `UPDATE` is followed by a single object name or alias (from the `FROM`), not multiple.

Comment: Exactly, this query is working perfectly fine in PHPMyadmin (MySql), and I want to implement the same thing in SqlServer. That's why added both tag. @Larnu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, the corresponding syntax might be:

```
UPDATE district
     SET state_name = s.state_name
    FROM state s
    WHERE district.state_id = s.id;
```

This is more commonly written using an explicit `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE d
     SET state_name = s.state_name
    FROM district d JOIN
         state s
         ON d.state_id = s.id;
```

However, you probably shouldn't be updating the value at all.  Just use a `JOIN` to get the state name when you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, will mark this as accepted once it working on my system.@Gordon

Comment: Probably should be `FROM district d` - not `FROM distinct d` :-)

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL, an `UPDATE` can only be followed by a single object afterwards. I suspect what you want woulkd be:

```sql
UPDATE d
SET state_name = s.state_name
FROM dbo.district d
     JOIN dbo.state ON d.state_id = s.id;
```